# clone img src to populate in specific other img source from click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this, but it isn't working:

```
  $('.prod_images').on('click', 'img', function() {
     var myElement = $(this);
     var img = myElement.clone();
     $('.imageprod').append(img);
  });
  $('.imageprod').on('click', 'img', function() {
     var myElement = $(this);
     var img = myElement.remove();
});
```

Basically `.prod_images` is the class of the images being clicked on.. I have a modal that opens when clicked on using a simple jquery `.show();` div. I would like the clicked on image's source to populate into the empty `<img src="" class="imageprod">` that is marked-up within my modal.

**Update:**
Essentially; I would like to update a specified image source via class selector, to update based on the specified image source clicked.

```
<img src="goose.jpg" class="clickme"><!-- image src one-->
```

When you click '`img .clickme`' a modal appears..

Within this modal there is an empty `<img src="" class="empty">`

I would like the `img` that was initially clicked, for it's `src` to populate the specified `.empty` one in my modal that appears.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `imageprod` the class of the image or the DIV that you're appending the image to?

Comment: Is is `class="empty"` or `class="imageprod"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what you're doing, but maybe this is it:

```
$('.prod_images'.on('click', 'img.clickme', function() {
    $('.empty').attr('src', this.src);
});
```

If you just want to copy the source from one element to another, you don't need to clone anything.